# What kind of questions are asked on the Metropolitan Kindergarten Readiness Test?

Tags: pre-schooler, primary-schooler

My child will begin school in a little over a year, and they will be administering the Metropolitan Kindergarten Readiness Test.

What kind of questions are asked on the Metropolitan Kindergarten Readiness Test? And how are the skills assessed?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is readily available via Google, for example here: http://college.cengage.com/education/salvia/assessment/10e/resources/salvia_test_metropolitan_readiness.pdf

From that link:

> **Beginning Reading**
>
> *Visual Discrimination (Level I)*   This is a Beginning Reading subtest that assesses skill in matching individual letters, letter
>   sequences, and words.
>
> *Beginning Consonants (Levels I and II)*   This is a Beginning Reading subtest that assesses skill in discriminating initial phonemes.
>
> *Sound–Letter Correspondence (Levels I and II)*   This is a Beginning Reading subtest that assesses skill in identifying letters that
>   correspond to sounds.
>
> *Aural Cloze (Level II)*   This is a Beginning Reading subtest that assesses skill in matching the initial sound of a picture that is
>   contextually appropriate for a sentence read by the examiner.
>
> **Story Comprehension (Levels I and II)**
>   This subtest assesses understanding of the vocabulary and concepts of a story to which
>   subjects listen.
>
> **Quantitative Concepts and Reasoning (Levels I and II)**
>   This subtest assesses basic mathematical concepts (such as number–numeral
>   and part–whole relationships) and operations (for example, addition).